# Notepad ++ How to remove all characters standing before a specific character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I searched all around but couldn't find any solutions.

I have:

```
<option value="1">Advertising
<option value="11">Aerospace
<option value="12">Agriculture
<option value="13">Architecture/Urban Planning
<option value="14">Arts
<option value="15">Automotive
<option value="16">Banking
<option value="17">Biotech & Pharmaceuticals
<option value="18">Business Services
<option value="19">Chemicals
```

I want delete all of text before the `">` so the unnecessary text like `<option value="1">` will be gone, only the Job type name such as `Advertising` being kept. How can I do it?

Comment: if testing on the example in question. replace `.*>` with empty would work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a regular expression search.

- Type ctrl-H to open the search-and-replace dialog.
- Make sure that "Regular expression" is checked.
- Put this in the "Find what" box: `^[^>]*>`
- Make sure that "Replace with" box is empty
- Click on "Replace All"

Done!

Explanation: The regular expression can be broken down as follows:

- `^` — match the start of a line
- `[^>]` — match any character that is not the > character
- `*` — repeat the previous as many times as possible
- `>` — match a > character

Comment: A little find before the replace All perhaps? to be sure

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - I tested it before posting. Besides, there's always ctrl-Z :)

Comment: And can we match a word instead of a char?

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could simply put the cursor between the `>` and `C` charters, then use `Alt` + `Shift` + `Up Arrow` to select multiple lines. Then hit the `backspace` key.

```
Cursor goes here--v--------
<option value="19">Chemicals
```

This assumes all the lines line up. Dead useful for manipulating these types of files. Works usually in other programs too (Visual Studio, SSMS, etc).

Answer (score 5):

Use regular expressions like this one:`<[^<]+?>` and replace with empty string

Comment: That should be `[^>]` instead of `[^<]`.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression .*">

Replace with empty

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).